# How to change the order of values in body

Tags: go, go-swagger

I am using go-swagger. Is there any way to make attribute in generated swagger have the same order as defined. In generated swagger it is sorted in alphabetical order.

This is my definition
[image]

This is generated swagger
[image]

Comment: See https://goswagger.io/faq/faq_model.html#generated-code-changes-the-order-of-properties-in-struct and https://goswagger.io/use/models/schemas.html#custom-extensions

Comment: @jub0bs where should i put it, it seem doesn't work

Comment: https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger/issues/2202

Comment: @medasx wow, so this is an unresolved issue and there is nothing I can do right?

Answer (score 1):

To get the order in generated schema you need to add `x-order` with `number` value within double quotes (`"`) or single quotes (`'`)

```golang
// swagger:parameters SaveAccountRequest
type SaveAccountRequestWrapper struct {
    // in:body
    Account SaveAccountRequest `json:"body"`
}

type SaveAccountRequest struct {
    // This text will appear as description of your request body.
    // in:body
    // Extensions:
    // x-order: "0"
    VendorID string `json:"vendorId"`
    // Extensions:
    // x-order: "1"
    VendorName string `json:"vendorName"`
    // Extensions:
    // x-order: "2"
    FullName string `json:"fullName"`
    // Extensions:
    // x-order: "3"
    Source string `json:"source"`
    // Extensions:
    // x-order: "4"
    Skill []string `json:"skill"`
    // Extensions:
    // x-order: "5"
    Phone string `json:"phone"`
    // Extensions:
    // x-order: "6"
    Email string `json:"email"`
    // Extensions:
    // x-order: "7"
    StartDate time.Time `json:"startDate"`
    // Extensions:
    // x-order: "8"
    EndDate time.Time `json:"endDate"`
}
```